# How to deal with this error?

Tags: error-handling, functional-programming, ocaml, overflow, large-data

I'm dealing with very long lists, and large trees.
Sometimes I would find this error:

```
surgery a;;
Characters 8-9:
  surgery a;;
          ^
Error: This expression has type int t/1044
       but an expression was expected of type 'a t/1810
# type 'a t = | Leaf of ('a -> 'a -> int)
            | Node of 'a * 'a t * 'a t * ('a -> 'a -> int)
```

I'm not sure about what type is that kind of error, but I guess it's some kind of an overflow. The type matches correctly but there are large numbers after the backslash that follows the type. In this case 1044 and 1810.
This time I have run some code before `surgery a`. If I kill the current top-level and start over, `surgery a` would run.

My questions are:
1. What is this error exactly?
2. When and how does it occur?
3. Why rerunning it from a new top-level would make it work?
4. How should I deal with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a type error, not a runtime error. It does not "cost" anything and is not in any way related to the size of the structures you have in memory.

It happens if you're not careful in the toplevel, and mix two different types with the *same name*. Compare:

```
type t = int;;
let f (x : t) = ();;
type u = bool;;
let g (y : u) = f y;;
                  ^
  Error: This expression has type u = bool
         but an expression was expected of type t = int
```

with

```
type t = int;;
let f (x : t) = ();;
type t = bool;;
let g (y : t) = f y;;
                  ^
  Error: This expression has type t/1047 = bool
         but an expression was expected of type t/1044 = int
```

This is the exact same typing error happening in both cases: you mixed different types. But in the second case, both have the same name `t`. The type-system tries to be helpful and tells you about the unique integers it internally assign to names, to make sure there are really unique throughout the program.

This kind of error cannot happen outside the toplevel (when compiling a program the usual way), as it is not possible to define two types with the same name at the exact same path.

How to fix it: if you redefine a type with a new definition that is not equivalent to the previous one, you must be careful to also redefine the operations on this previous type previously recorded in the toplevel. Indeed, they are still typed as expecting the old type, and using them with the new type will result in such errors.

Comment: Is that new ? I never saw that before.

Comment: @gasche : Thanks for you explanation. That should be the problem.